# Bounded linear operator and inverse

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two bounded invertible linear operator on Banach space $E$.  Suppose for $t\in $some interval, $A+tB$ is also invertible.   My question is:

> Is operator $(A+tB)^{-1}$ is bounded uniformly for all $t\in$ some interval of $0$?

Comment: I mean an operator $A: E\to E$ is invertible if there exists an operator $B: E\to E$ such that $AB= BA= Id$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is true in a general context, and the hypothesis that $A+tB$ is invertible for small $t$ is vacuous, as it follows from the fact that $A$ is invertible ($B$ doesn't need to be invertible).

This follows from the fact that in any (unital) Banach algebra $\mathbf A$ (like that of bounded operators on a Banach space), the set of invertible elements $\mathcal G (\mathbf A)$ is open and inversion is continuous as a map from $\mathcal G(\mathbf A)$ to itself.

Comment: thnks for the answers

Comment: I guess this type of result may not true in when we take Fr\'{e}chet space in place of Banach space.  Can i have some reference to read. Thanks .

Comment: It's probably in any book containing an introduction to Banach algebras. You can also google it, this if the first result for "inverse is continuous Banach algebras": http://homepage.ntlworld.com/ivan.wilde/notes/calg/calg.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Let $D=(A+tB)$. Since $Dx=y \in Y$, $x=D^{-1}y$ If we pick $\|x\| < 1$, then $\|y\| \leq \rho$, where $\rho$ is a number defined by $D$ (continuity of linear operators on Banach spaces). Then $\|x\| = \|D^{-1}y\| \leq 1$. Pick $z \in Y$. Then $\| D^{-1}z\| = \| D^{-1} \frac{z}{\|z\|}\rho \frac{\|z\|}{\rho}\| = \frac{\|z\|}{\rho}\|D^{-1} \frac{z}{\|z\|} \rho\| = c\|D^{-1}\xi\|\|z\|$, where $c=\frac{1}{\rho}, \xi=\frac{z}{\|z\|}\rho \in Y$. Since $\|\xi\| = \rho$, $\|D^{-1}\xi\| \leq 1$ , and $\|D^{-1}z\| \leq c\|z\|$, i.e., $D^{-1}$ is bounded. Moreover, $\|D^{-1}\| \leq \frac{1}{\rho}$. Selecting $\rho_* > \|A\| + \max(t) \|B\|$ should yield uniform boundedness.

Does this answer the question?

Comment: What do you mean by "$y$ is bounded"? And how does it follow that $(A+tB)^{-1}$ is bounded, especially uniformly?

Comment: I meant that $\|y\| < \infty$ and hence you can divide through by $\|y\|$.

Comment: Isn't that true for any $y$??? And how is that even relevant?

Comment: If `A+tB` is unbounded, `y` can be too - this is what I meant.

Comment: A vector in a normed space can't be unbounded. Neither can a linear combination of bounded operators...

Comment: Agreed. But the boundedness of A and B is stipulated in the condition...

Comment: @DoctorDan, can you pls be more precise.. and explain Tomsaz comment #2